# How to make webpack print more information on each watch build

Tags: webpack

Every time I change the file during `webpack -d --watch` I would like the timestamp of the build attempt to be displayed:

```
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  791 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  867 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 178 hidden modules
Hash: 956920f898995d29902e
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 393ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  791 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  867 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 178 hidden modules
Hash: 18a827379b45b7a477dd
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 416ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  792 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  869 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 180 hidden modules
Hash: 41d620143e3b87371f0a
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 327ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  792 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  869 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 180 hidden modules
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following discussion in the webpack repo. The method of having a plugin works perfectly.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1499